# how to locate ndk into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I downloaded android ndk from google website this is the link:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip
```

But i don't know how to locate it in android studio

[image: android studio ndk location]

Comment: What happens if you click "..." button for opening NDK directory?

Comment: nothing it is disabled by default

Comment: try Download link or go to settings -> plugins and click install plugin from disk

Comment: @maatik5 I did as you said but i got this error from android studio
'Fail to load plugin descriptor from file android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

I located ndk dir manually in my app project by adding `ndk.dir=E\:\\android-ndk-r12b` at the end of `local.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

just go to your android studio and click on file and go to project structure and you see there a chose about ndk thin put the NDK location seethe image bellow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpunM.png)

Comment: include your image in with your answer for better understanding.